# Symfony memcached PDOException Unique violation

Tags: symfony, doctrine, memcached, unique

I'm developing application using Symfony 2.4 with Doctrine. As caching system i'm using Memcached via BabelCache (http://docs.webvariants.de/babelcache/latest/).

When i start my memcached server application start working very strange, when I made changes on object which I earlier put into cache, my application throws " Unique violation: 7 ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint". It's strange because object exist in database. When I turn memcached server off everything works fine.

I started debugging problem and it's seems that Doctrine threat this object as new(It's sets entityState to STATE_DETACHED in UnitOfWork.php).

Have anyone can help me with this problem?(I'm new in Symfony). What my be causing this problem?

Thx, for help.